# Kendo Cascade DropDownList MVC keep selected value after initial loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I´m developing a CRUD application and I have a cascade dropdownlist working fine in my Create view :

```
@Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.CarSelected).BindTo(Model.Cars)

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(x => x.CarModelSelected).DataTextField("Name").DataValueField("Id")
  .Enable(false).AutoBind(false).OptionLabel("Select"))
  .CascadeFrom("CarSelected")     
  .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("CarModels", "Car")
              .Data("filter")).ServerFiltering(true))
```

That works great...

But in a Edit view, I have to previous load the car model selected, so I have something like that :

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  var car = repository.load(id);
  CarVm carVm = car.InjectFrom(car);
  ...
  carVm.CarModelSelected = car.Model.Id;

  return View(carVm);
}
```

It works great and my inital Edit view is loaded fine... 
Now when I change the car, it loads all car model (cascade) but the CarModelSelected keep the inital value, and the CarModel DropDown dont reset to OptionLabel "Select" .

So, If open a View with :Car A Model AB, change car to "Select", and after select Car A again, the model AB will be selected automatically

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed in the newest internal Kendo build

Paul